# How to describe all points with coordinates that are permutations of sets of values for x and y using notation correctly

Tags: notation

Suppose I have a set of values for x: something like {1, 2} and another set for y: {3,4}. If I need to list all the possible points which coordinates are permutations of those sets and I don't want to list them explicitly, how would I do it? Best I can do is P(x,y):{x$\in${1,2}, y$\in${3,4}}, but I think it's wrong. How should it be notated correctly?

Comment: You seem to be using words incorrectly.  Are you able to explicitly write out the result of the operation without set builder notation?  Are you perhaps looking for $\{(1,3),(1,4),(2,3),(2,4)\}$?  How do "*permutations*" come into this?

Comment: @JMoravitz , you are right. Sorry, I'm still figuring out all the names, but the closest concept I know is permutations, so I called it permutation :) By 'explicitly' I mean writing down all points like P(1, 3), P(1, 4), P(2, 3), P(2, 4).

Comment: I don't believe you should be including these $P$'s in what you write either.  I suppose it isn't explicitly *wrong*... but certainly confusing, cluttering, and unnecessary.  It is perfectly acceptable to refer to "*the point $(1,3)$.*"

Comment: @JMoravitz I just solved a problem where the answer is a set of 9 points, so I figured it would be much prettier to use some sort of notation. Can I give an answer in a form like: X= {some values} and Y={some other values} Answer : Point (x, y): (x, y)$\in$X×Y or it is nonsense?

Comment: "*where the answer* **is a set** *of 9 points*"  So then, your answer can be $X\times Y$.  No need to talk about $\{(x,y)~:~(x,y)\in X\times Y\}$, that is redundant.

Comment: @JMoravitz understood, many thanks for you answer

Answer (score 1):

Say $X=\left\{1,2\right\}$ and $Y=\left\{3,4\right\}$, you're looking for the *cartesian product*: $$X\times Y=\left\{(x,y):x \in X, y\in Y\right\}=\left\{(1,3),(1,4),(2,3),(2,4)\right\}.$$